# Docker Go image: starting container process caused: exec: "app": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: docker, go, environment-variables

I have been reading a lot of similar issues on different languages, none of them are Go.

I just created a Dockerfile with the instructions I followed on [official Docker hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang):

```
FROM golang:1.17.3

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

CMD ["app"]
```

This is my folder structure:

```
users-service
 |-> .gitignore
 |-> Dockerfile
 |-> go.mod
 |-> main.go
 |-> README.md
```

If anyone needs to see some code, this is how my `main.go` looks like:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
}
```

1. I ran `docker build -t users-service .`:

```
$ docker build -t users-service .
[+] Building 5.5s (11/11) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 154B                                                                                                                               0.1s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.17.3                                                                                                   3.3s
 => [auth] library/golang:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/golang:1.17.3@sha256:6556ce40115451e40d6afbc12658567906c9250b0fda250302dffbee9d529987                                             0.3s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                  0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 2.05kB                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => [2/5] WORKDIR /go/src/app                                                                                                                                      0.1s
 => [3/5] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                 0.1s
 => [4/5] RUN go get -d -v ./...                                                                                                                                   0.6s 
 => [5/5] RUN go install -v ./...                                                                                                                                  0.7s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                             0.2s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                            0.1s 
 => => writing image sha256:1f0e97ed123b079f80eb259dh3e34c90a48bf93e8f55629d05044fec8bfcaca6                                                                       0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/users-service                                                                                                                   0.0s 

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
```

2. Then I ran `docker run users-service` but I get that error:

> $ docker run users-service
>
> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "app": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

I remember I had some troubles with `GOPATH` environment variable in Visual Studio Code on Windows, maybe it's related... Any sugguestions?

Comment: Can you share any code related to app?

Comment: Also add the output of the build command, even if it seems to be ok.

Comment: @jabbson added.

Comment: I see your original folder is named `users-service`, but you are copying the source into `app` folder expecting that compiled executable will be named after it. But it's actually will use name from module declaration. If `go.mod` declares `module users-service`, then your Dockerfile command should be `CMD ["users-service"]`. Or change module name to `app` in go.mod.

Comment: You could to use ./app as  CMD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official Docker documentation has useful instructions for building a Go image: https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/build-images/

---

In summary, you need to build your Go binary and you need to configure the CMD appropriately, e.g.:

```
FROM golang:1.17.3

WORKDIR /app

COPY main.go .
COPY go.mod ./

RUN go build -o /my-go-app

CMD ["/my-go-app"]
```

Build the container:

```
$ docker build -t users-service .
```

Run the docker container:

```
$ docker run --rm -it users-service
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Yep, that did work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your "app" executable binary should be available in your `$PATH` to call globally without any path prefix. Otherwise, you have to supply your full path to your executable like `CMD ["/my/app"]`

Also, I recommend using an `ENTRYPOINT` instruction. `ENTRYPOINT` indicates the direct path to the executable, while `CMD` indicates arguments supplied to the `ENTRYPOINT`.

Using combined `RUN` instructions make your image layers minimal, your overall image size becomes little bit smaller compared to using multiple `RUN`s.

Comment: (I generally recommend using `CMD` over `ENTRYPOINT`; it's much easier to, for example, `docker run --rm -it users-service /bin/sh` to get an interactive debugging shell on the image to find where the binary actually is, and there is a frequently-helpful pattern of using `ENTRYPOINT` to do first-time setup and then launch the `CMD` as the main container command.)